# BundleException: Missing Constraint:Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt; version="0.0.0"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, osgi-bundle

I am trying to launch an RCP application(Product) using "--console". I got few conflicts but not sure how to resolve this particular conflict.

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle 
"com.company.abc.app_1.5 [111]" could not be resolved. 
Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt; version="0.0.0"
    at 
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1327)
```

On checking the the dependencies which I think I should look at, I found the following in com.company.abc.app:

```
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.ui:org.eclipse.ui.workbench:jar:3.106.2-SDK-4.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.help:org.eclipse.help:jar:3.6.0-SDK-4.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jface:org.eclipse.jface.databinding:jar:1.6.200-SDK-4.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.core:org.eclipse.core.databinding:jar:1.4.2-SDK-4.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.core:org.eclipse.core.databinding.property:jar:1.4.200-SDK-4.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.core:org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable:jar:1.4.1-SDK-4.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- **org.eclipse.e4:org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt:jar:0.12.100-SDK-4.4.2:compile**
```

Though I do not see any org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt in the product. When I searched in maven repo I did not find org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt v0.12.100-SDK-4.4.2. That's bit confusing.

Also, I do not completely understand why it complains about version 0.0.0 in *Missing Constraint: Import-Package: org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt; version="0.0.0"* ?

Comment: Version 0.0.0 just means it doesn't care about the version.  Package 'org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt' is in the 'org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt' plug-in.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks but the earliest version of org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt is 0.14(https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.platform/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt) but in this case its pulling 0.12.100-SDK-4.4.2.

Comment: There has been a version of org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt in every Eclipse 4 release starting with 0.9.1 in Eclipse 4.0. You should be getting all your Eclipse plugins from Eclipse repositories, preferably using a target platform and using Eclipse Tycho